# convert an Array, converted to a String, back to an Array JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript

I have this object :

```
let startCourseData = {
    'slidesHistory': '[{ id: 1, difficulty: 4, performance: 100, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "A", plan: false, planned: 10 },{ id: 2, difficulty: 4, performance: 30, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "A", plan: false, planned: 0 },{ id: 3, difficulty: 4, performance: 60, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "A", plan: false, planned: 6 },{ id: 4, difficulty: 4, performance: 80, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "B", plan: false, planned: 5 },{ id: 5, difficulty: 4, performance: 80, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "B", plan: false, planned: 6 },{ id: 6, difficulty: 4, performance: 82, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "A", plan: false, planned: 10 },{ id: 7, difficulty: 4, performance: 90, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "C", plan: false, planned: 9 },{ id: 8, difficulty: 4, performance: 90, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "C", plan: false, planned: 8 },{ id: 9, difficulty: 4, performance: 90, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "B", plan: false, planned: 5 },];'
};
```

And I want to convert `slidesHistory` that is a string to an array so I used JSON.parse like this:

```
const slidesHistorys = JSON.parse(startCourseData.slidesHistory);
console.log(slidesHistorys);
```

But I get an error!

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 3

How can I fix this?

Comment: your keys does not have double quotes, like `"id: 1"` or in short it is not [ECMA-404](https://json.org/) conform

Comment: why use a string at all?

Comment: You have invalid JSON. I'm not sure why you're storing it this way but I suggest fixing the encoding.

Comment: The key for the object in the array should have double quotes like this: `[{ "id": 1, "difficulty": 4, ....}]`

Comment: I want to store `slidesHistory` into a database as a string.. isn't it a good idea...??

Comment: @foxer probably not but at the very least it's not absolutely terrible. Still, you should *properly encode it as JSON*, so you can properly read it as JSON afterwards.

Comment: How would you do it ... I mean storing  `slidesHistory` inside the database?

Comment: @foxer "How to store it inside the database" is a different question which you should have in a new post.

Comment: ok.. I'll do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `eval`

```js
let startCourseData = {
    'slidesHistory': '[{ id: 1, difficulty: 4, performance: 100, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "A", plan: false, planned: 10 },{ id: 2, difficulty: 4, performance: 30, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "A", plan: false, planned: 0 },{ id: 3, difficulty: 4, performance: 60, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "A", plan: false, planned: 6 },{ id: 4, difficulty: 4, performance: 80, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "B", plan: false, planned: 5 },{ id: 5, difficulty: 4, performance: 80, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "B", plan: false, planned: 6 },{ id: 6, difficulty: 4, performance: 82, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "A", plan: false, planned: 10 },{ id: 7, difficulty: 4, performance: 90, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "C", plan: false, planned: 9 },{ id: 8, difficulty: 4, performance: 90, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "C", plan: false, planned: 8 },{ id: 9, difficulty: 4, performance: 90, guided_phrases: [], sequence: "B", plan: false, planned: 5 },];'
};

const slidesHistorys = eval(startCourseData.slidesHistory);
console.log(slidesHistorys);
```